# Map Reduce program to merge multiple xml files to a single xml file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Hindsight & Hadoop map reduce concept. I am trying to merge multiple XML files to a single XML file using map reduce program. My intention is to merge each XML file into a destination XML file by prepending and appending file name as start and end tag.
For eg. the below XML's should be merged into a single XML shown below

Input XML Files

```
<xml><a></a></xml>
<xml><b></b></xml>
<xml><c></c></xml>
```

Output XML File

```
<xml>
 <File1Name><xml><a></a></xml><File2Name>
 <File2Name><xml><b></b></xml><File3Name>
 <File3Name><xml><c></c></xml><File3Name>
<xml>
```

Question 1: Is it possible to map a XML file to each mapper and create a key value pair, key as a file name and value as an each XML file prepending and appending file name as start and end tags and reducer to merge all XML's to  a single context and output to XML shown above.

Question 2: How can i get file name as key in mapper code?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:
I don't suggest sending just a single XML to a mapper unless the files are over 1gb a piece. You can send a list of xml locations to your mapper and then in your mapper code open each location and extract the data into your output.

Answer 2:
If using azure blob storage, you could list all the blobs in a container and assign them to the input split.

```
How to create your list of InputSplits:
ArrayList<InputSplit> ret = new ArrayList<InputSplit>();

/*Do this for each path we receive.  Creates a directory of splits in this order s = input path (S1,1),(s2,1)…(sN,1),(s1,2),(sN,2),(sN,3) etc..
 */
for (int i = numMinNameHashSplits; i <=     Math.min(numMaxNameHashSplits,numNameHashSplits–1); i++) {
for (Path inputPath : inputPaths) {
  ret.add(new ParseDirectoryInputSplit(inputPath.toString(), i));
  System.out.println(i + ” “+inputPath.toString());
 }
 }
return ret;
  }
 }

Once the List<InputSplits> is assembled, each InputSplit is handed to a Record Reader class where each Key, Value, pair is read then passed to the map task.  The initialization of the recordreader class uses the InputSplit, a string representing the location of a “folder” of invoices in blob storage, to return a list of all blobs within the folder, the blobs variable below.  The below Java code demonstrates the creation of the record reader for each hashslot and the resulting list of blobs in that location.

Public class ParseDirectoryFileNameRecordReader

extends RecordReader<IntWritable, Text> {
private int nameHashSlot;
private int numNameHashSlots;
private Path myDir;
private Path currentPath;
private Iterator<ListBlobItem> blobs;
private int currentLocation;

public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   myDir = ((ParseDirectoryInputSplit)split).getDirectoryPath();

//getNameHashSlot tells us which slot this record reader is responsible for
   nameHashSlot = ((ParseDirectoryInputSplit)split).getNameHashSlot();

//gets the total number of hashslots
   numNameHashSlots = getNumNameHashSplits(context.getConfiguration());

//gets the input credientals to the storage account assigned to this record reader.
   String inputCreds = getInputCreds(context.getConfiguration());

//break the directory path to get account name    
   String[] authComponents = myDir.toUri().getAuthority().split(“@”);
   String accountName = authComponents[1].split(“\\.”)[0];
   String containerName = authComponents[0];
   String accountKey = Utils.returnInputkey(inputCreds, accountName);
   System.out.println(“This mapper is assigned the following     account:”+accountName);
StorageCredentials creds = new        StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName,accountKey);
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds);
   CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer container =        client.getContainerReference(containerName);
blobs = container.listBlobs(myDir.toUri().getPath().substring(1) +     “/”,     true,EnumSet.noneOf(BlobListingDetails.class), null,null).iterator();
   currentLocation = –1;
return;
 }

Once initialized, the record reader is used to pass the next key to the map task.  This is controlled by the nextKeyValue method, and it is called every time map task starts.  The blow Java code demonstrates this.




//This checks if the next key value is assigned to this task or is assigned to another mapper.  If it assigned to this task the location is passed to the mapper, otherwise return false
 @Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
while (blobs.hasNext()) {
  ListBlobItem currentBlob = blobs.next();

//Returns a number between 1 and number of hashslots. If it matches the number assigned to this Mapper and its length is greater than 0, return the path to the map function
  if (doesBlobMatchNameHash(currentBlob) && getBlobLength(currentBlob) > 0) {
String[] pathComponents = currentBlob.getUri().getPath().split(“/”);

String pathWithoutContainer =
currentBlob.getUri().getPath().substring(pathComponents[1].length() + 1);

currentPath = new Path(myDir.toUri().getScheme(),     myDir.toUri().getAuthority(),pathWithoutContainer);

currentLocation++;
return true;
 }
    }
return false;
 }

The logic in the map function is than simply as follows, with inputStream containing the entire XML string

Path inputFile = new Path(value.toString());
FileSystem fs = inputFile.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());

//Input stream contains all data from the blob in the location provided by Text
FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(inputFile);
```

**Resources:**

http://www.andrewsmoll.com/3-hacks-for-hadoop-and-hdinsight-clusters/  "Hack 3"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/04/10/merging-small-files-on-hdinsight.aspx

Comment: Thanks Andrew for clear explanation. I will check this now and implement.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. If it works for you please mark as answer :)